# Browser Developer Tools: Disable Warnings in 3rd Party Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

When developing for the web, is there *any* way to mark a script as an upstream or third-party asset so that warnings from said script will be ignored by the developer tools in your browser or to suppress either specific warnings or warnings in specific files?

For example, I have no interest that Bootstrap isn't using `Object.create()` in a certain instance and don't care about that warning - I have better things to do than to go fix it.

> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create

(Lots of things raise this warning - not just Bootstrap 4.0.0-alpha.2)

I care mostly about Firefox and Chrome but it would be cool if there was a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome Devtools, you can filter for your current context in the settings of the console window, as shown in the screenshots in this [superuser post](https://superuser.com/a/1028554/447662).